# Swift + Storyboards: How to keep strong reference to show segue controller?

Tags: ios, swift

I have two controllers:

1. HistoryViewController, which has a "Browse" button. This is embedded inside a NavigationController
2. WebBrowserViewController, which will be accessed through the browse button from the HistoryViewController

The browse button is hooked up fine. When I tap on it, it takes me to the web browser view storyboard.

[image]

However, it always makes a new web browser view when I press back and tap on the "Browse" button again. Therefore, if I'm on a certain page in the web browser view and I go back to the history view, and then tap "Browse" again, I always go back to the homepage and lose my current page.

Is there a way to keep a strong reference to the WebBrowserViewController so that only the initial tap to the "Browse" button will create the web browser and all following taps just show that one?

I'm using storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segues always create a new viewController.  If you want to return to the same `WebBrowserViewController` repeatedly, then you should instantiate that view controller manually, keep a strong reference to it in your `HistoryViewController`, and then push or present that viewController instead of using a segue.

```
var webBrowserVC: WebBrowserViewController?

@IBAction func browseButtonPressed() {
    if webBrowserVC == nil {
        webBrowserVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("webBrowserViewController") as? WebBrowserViewController
    }

    // configure webBrowserVC with data that would have previously been set
    // in prepareForSegue:
    webBrowserVC?.someProperty = someData

    // push view controller if you are using a navigation controller:
    navigationController?.pushViewController(webBrowserVC!, animated: true)

    // or to present modally:
    presentViewController(webBrowserVC!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In order for this to work, you have to set the *Storyboard Identifier* to `"webBrowserViewController"` in the *Identity Inspector*.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to keep a strong reference to the WebBrowserViewController

That wouldn't be the right thing to do. Instead, keep a strong reference to the *configuration information* that you would need in order to *recreate* the state of the web browser view controller when you return to it.

(For example, you can save the request URL and even the scroll offset of the web view.)

Comment: is there an easier way without explicitly storing the state? i'd rather just present the same view controller or something

Comment: Well, you could use a tab bar controller instead of a Show segue... A tab bar controller keeps multiple view controllers on hand as siblings. Or you could even build your own view controller architecture. But if you are going to use a Show segue, you should not present "the same view controller"; letting the view controller die when you leave it, and instantiating a new one when you Show again, is the whole _point_ of this aspect of the view controller architecture.

Comment: Storing the state *is* the easier way.